# Popup error message while trying to submit form without valid data in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, validation

I am using angularJs form validation as follows,

```
    <form  ng-submit="submit()" name="form" novalidate class="css-form">
     <input type="text" name='email' ng-model='formData.email' required>
     <span class="error" ng-show="errorData.email != null">{{errorData.email}}</span>
<input type="submit" value="Login" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">
```

and css

```
    input.ng-invalid.ng-touched{
    border:1px solid red;
}

input.ng-valid.ng-touched{
    border:1px solid blue;
}

input[required].ng-pristine{
    /*border:1px solidred;*/
}
input.ng-valid.ng-dirty{
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

When user typing in text box,error message works properly.But if user click submit button directly,it is not showing error and submitting the form without validating. 
I want to show validation error if user click submit button.How it is possible in angularJs form validation.

Comment: can you post your controller too? so that we can recreate your error and try to fix?

Comment: I need just client side error validation only

Comment: do you mean that ng-disabled is not working if you don't type anything in the input?

Comment: no..if i am typing in input field.. the textbox border color is red until user enter valid email.but when user click login button directly,it submitting the form.here I want to show email text box border color red and form should not be submitted.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your form is being submitted is that your form is in fact valid.
Change your input into this:

```
<input type="email" name='email' ng-model='formData.email' required>
```

i.e. change type into email so that angular can validate the input as email.